# How can I check if array is exists for the imagesid and for the imgs to avoiding Undefined offset error?

Tags: php, arrays, exists

I want to check if the array is exists for the imagesid and the imgs or the imagesid and the imgs had the same value and it's not throwing an `Notice: Undefined offset:` error message.

I have this code to get the related images for the posts:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM multiple_image";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $imgs[$row['imageid']][$row['id']]= "<img width='' src='../images/".$row['name']."' >"; // array of image id's, with arrays of images inside them.
  } 

 }
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $commentsToImages[$row['commentid']] = $row['imagesid']; // array of post id's to picture ids
      $comments[$row['commentid']] = $row['comment']; // array of post id's to comment text.
  } 

 }
```

This code is rendering all the related images with the content:

```
foreach($commentsToImages as $commentID =>$imagesID) {
    ?>
<div class='main'>
  <div class='comments'>
<?php echo $comments[$commentID]; // render the comment ?>
  </div>
  <div class='pics'>
    <?php
          foreach($imgs[$imagesID] as $img) { // foreach loop that will render all the images...
                  echo $img;
          }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Indeed, just a typo, but that's not answered my question.

Comment: What I want to do is just doing an `if` statemnt to check if it is not throwing an error or some value is missing.

Comment: No, I am not getting error. Just want to wrap in a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like not all posts have image(s). You probably want to make sure there exists an `$imgs[$imagesID]` before this line `foreach($imgs[$imagesID] as $img)` executes. One solution would be to "wrap" the foreach in an `if(isset($imgs[$imagesID])`

Comment: Yeah, it does for the images only but I wrapped the comments and images to the `if(isset($imgs[commentID])`. So if there is no issue with the key (`imagesid`) than it will show the commments with the related imgs :) I wanted to do for the comments as well, not just for the images. This helped me out.